# Error launching browser when i am running a selenium with java in eclipse?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Its my program**

package Projectpack; import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; public class Projectclass { /** * @param args */ public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Users\admins\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"); WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); driver.get("https://www.youtube.com"); System.out.println("Aryanow Opened"); driver.close(); } }

**Its my error**

Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.134 (8ec6fce403b3feb0869b0732eda8bd95011d333c-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#1262}) on port 21341
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Aug 04, 2022 2:10:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils killWinProcess
WARNING: Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final long java.lang.ProcessImpl.handle accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to module selenium.server.standalone
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:130)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:247)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$2(UnixProcess.java:246)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:125)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:155)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:196)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:94)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:526)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:134)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
at Selenium/Sekeniumpack.Login.main(Login.java:16)

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-GS6R0N19', ip: '192.168.18.42', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at selenium.server.standalone@2.53.1/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)

Answer (score 0):

```
pom.xml Entries :
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
 ****************************************
```

// Write the below code in you main method

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://demo.anhtester.com/basic-checkbox-demo.html");
        

    enter code here
```

Comment: Tq its working because i am  creating the normal project now i am trying in maven projecyt its working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).